# separte columns from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame results from extracting data from text files which have some columns which contains more than a value

I want to split columns with more than a value into 2 columns like this

I tried this code but it generates an error

```
db<-separate_rows(db,TYPE,CHRO,EX ,sep=",\\s+")
Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide `dput(db)` of your data sample so that we can test solutions?

Comment: Additionally, is it the case that where multiple values exist for a column, they also exist for other columns? E.g `TYPE` has 2 values on row 3, and so does `EX`. Could one ever have multiple values when the other doesn't?

Comment: So what do you propose is the correct result when this happens? Here you duplicate other values for the first row, but then match the values in order in row 3. What if in one row, a column has 2 values but another column has 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that sample data and expected output don't match; for example, there is no `CHRO=c700` entry in your sample data. You also seem to be missing rows. Please check your input/expected output data.**

You could use `tidyr::separate_rows`, e.g.

```
df %>%
    separate_rows(TYPE, sep = ",") %>%
    separate_rows(CHRO, sep = ",") %>%
    separate_rows(EX, sep = ",")
#    TYPE       CHRO     EX
#1       multiple   c.211dup   <NA>
#2       multiple  c.3751dup   <NA>
#3       multiple       <NA> exon.2
#4       multiple       <NA> exon.3
#5       multiple       <NA> exon.7
#6   mitocondrial       <NA> exon.3
#7   mitocondrial       <NA> exon.7
#8 multifactorial       <NA>   <NA>
```

---

Or perhaps use `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
df %>%
    cSplit(names(df), direction = "long") %>%
    fill(TYPE) %>%
    group_by_at(names(df)) %>%
    slice(1)
#  TYPE           CHRO      EX
#  <fct>          <fct>     <fct>
#1 mitocondrial   NA        exon.7
#2 multifactorial NA        NA
#3 multiple       c.211dup  NA
#4 multiple       c.3751dup NA
#5 multiple       NA        exon.2
#6 multiple       NA        exon.3
#7 multiple       NA        NA
```

Note that results are different because the order of separating columns matters.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "TYPE                   CHRO                       EX
        multiple    'c.211dup, c.3751dup'                       NA
        multiple                     NA                   exon.2
        multiple,mitocondrial        NA                   exon.3,exon.7
  multifactorial                     NA                       NA", header = T)
```

Comment: If OP is ok with the product set of alternatives for `TYPE` and `EX`, this is the answer.